# React native basic calculation with TextInputs

Tags: react-native

I want to creat different TextInputs (e.g. 2 Textinputs a & b, 1 Button, then predefined calculation e.g. a + b, one output feld) then calculate  something with them and then output it after pressing a button below. How is best fastest way to do it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    firstValue: '',
    secondValue: '',
    sum: 0
  };
}

calculateSum = () => {
  const { firstValue, secondValue } = this.state;

  this.setState({
    sum: Number(firstValue) + Number(secondValue)
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        value={this.state.firstValue}
        onChangeText={(firstValue) => this.setState({firstValue})}
      />

      <TextInput
        value={this.state.secondValue}
        onChangeText={(secondValue) => this.setState({secondValue})}
      />

      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.calculateSum}>
        <Text>Calculate</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>

      <Text>{`Sum ${this.state.sum}`}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Then you would need to check that the input values actually are convertable to numbers and addable. You can use `keyboardType` for `TextInput` depending on your need. E.g. `keyboardType="numeric"` will not support negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I integrated it and made a new init cal

then I get: an unexpected token error.